# Xml schema serialization of complextype with data annotation validations

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, data-annotations, complextype

I have the following schema part:

```
<xs:element name="authorizationNumber" type="authorizationIdType">
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="authorizationIdType">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="authorizationIdNumber" type="authorizationNumberType">
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="authorizationIdFree" type="xs:string">
        </xs:element>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleType name="authorizationNumberType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:length value="17"/>
        <xs:pattern value="(0[1-9]|1[0-9])(P0[1-3]|G0[1-5]|T0[1-2])\d{12}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I generated the class.cs from the schema including data annotations (with xsd2code++) so i can validate the object. The corresponding part of the class.cs is like this:

```
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public authorizationIdType authorizationNumber { get; set; }


[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="x")]
public partial class authorizationIdType
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("authorizationIdFree", typeof(string), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("authorizationIdNumber", typeof(string), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemElementName")]
    public object Item { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public ItemChoiceType2 ItemElementName { get; set; }
}
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="x", IncludeInSchema=false)]
public enum ItemChoiceType2
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute(":authorizationIdFree")]
    authorizationIdFree,
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute(":authorizationIdNumber")]
    authorizationIdNumber
}
```

The problem is that as its a complex type the data annotations doesnt get included, but i dont know in this case how to include them as the have to be applied only when the public object Item is of the type authorizationIdNumber.

In a simple case of another element for example the annotations get generated like this:

```
 [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute(5)]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RegularExpressionAttribute("[0-9]{5}")]
    public string PostalCode{ get; set; }
```

Maybe the line:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("authorizationIdNumber", typeof(string), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
```

Should be something like:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("authorizationIdNumber", typeof(authorizationNumberType), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
```

And create a class type that holds the string value with the data annotations? This is the part that i dont know exactly how to code so the serialization and attribute instantiation continues working fine but with the Data Annotations validation included.